# loadString(...) - access to JS functions

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flex4, air

I'm loading website by using `htmlLoader.loadString(someHtml)`. There are included JS sources.
Is there any chance to get access to functions which are inside this JS file?

I also set property `placeLoadStringContentInApplicationSandbox` to true.

Comment: What exactly are you doing, and why do you need this functionality?  What's the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is your best friend my friend. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_02.html

More specifically, http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_07.html

Comment: cool but when you trying to load JS from app-storage or user directory this fail..

Comment: But this issue seems a bit irrelevant to your question. What do you mean it fails? Is there a security issue that you can't even load the HTML source? Then, you can't use JS of course. I'm not sure if this would help but http://forums.adobe.com/thread/435399 In one of my AIR projects, I was able to pull a password protected zip file, open it on the fly, find an HTML file and extract the data. If I remember well, I even used some JS function in it. Maybe some code would help us.

Answer (score 0):

Question is, how to get access to JS function - showAlert()? In this case I used userDirectory to store files. Both files - txt (which has html source inside) and JS - are in this directory - /Users/unsername/. Hope that now everything will be clear. Thanks for help.

```
private function init():void
        {
        var testFile:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("testreadonly.txt");

        var readFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        readFileStream.open(testFile, FileMode.READ);
        var test:String = readFileStream.readMultiByte(testFile.size, File.systemCharset);

        var myJS:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("myJS.js");

        trace("my JS : " + myJS.exists);//it shows TRUE

        myHTML.htmlLoader.placeLoadStringContentInApplicationSandbox = true;
        myHTML.htmlLoader.loadString(test);
        }
```

My HMTL file source:

```
<html><body><script type='text/javascript' src='myJS.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>showAlert()</script>Pawel</body></html>
```

My JS file:

```
function showAlert()
{
    alert('alert');
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember, my JS function was in the HTML code. I see that you're trying to access external JS files. As a proof of concept, could you try to integrate JS into HTML and try to access it? Then we can at least know that it works because there might be some other issues to work out : Security, file permission etc. Let's take it one step at a time.